# Using IF to compare result of a variable - Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, var

I want to compare the result of this variable:

```
set "var=type list.txt | find /c /v "" "
```

How do I check if the result of this command equals to "26"?

I tried some things like that, but it didn't work:

```
@echo off
set "var=type list.txt | find /c /v "" "
IF "%var%"=="26" (
    ECHO bingo
)
pause
```

Is guess it's comparing the content of var instead of its result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  Batch files are not like `BASH`.  To capture the result of a command with a batch file you need to use the `FOR /F` command.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me an example of how to use FOR /F in this case? I'm really not familiar with batch scripts.

Comment: Thank you, mate.

Comment: `type list.txt | find /c /v "" |set /p "var="` load first line

Comment: @penknife, did you test that code?